# PayPal token expiration

Tags: php, paypal

I am using **https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr** for make PayPal payment. When any user clicks on **PayNow** button it will navigate to the PayPal Page where the user enters their credential but somehow user remain on the same page and not do anything. And come after 2 hours, so it is still able to access that URL.

I need to expire that URL after 15 mins. If anyone has some suggestion regarding that, please share it.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use In-Context Checkout buttons you may be able to control the checkout experience and timing.  There is not a way to do it with the traditional, leave-your-site paypal express checkout.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/enable_in_context_checkout/

Comment: Please see the above-attached snap. Maybe it will clear you. I am talking about above page expiration.

Comment: Yes, you have no control or input over how long they can stay on that page.  Switch to In-Context where you will be closer to keeping them on your site.